# Update a property when another property changes in Prism

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

I have something like that in my view model

```
        public ObservableCollection<string> UnitSystems { get; set; }
        private string selectedUnitSystem;
        public string SelectedUnitSystem
        {
            get { return selectedUnitSystem; }
            set { SetProperty(ref selectedUnitSystem, value); }
        }

        private string _property1Unit;
        public string Property1Unit
        {
            get { return _property1Unit; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _property1Unit, value); }
        }
```

They are bound to a combobox and label in my view. I want to update the value Property1Unit and content of the label of course, when I select something else in my combobox. Is it possible?

Comment: When you want to show the selected item in the Label then bind the Label to SelectedUnitSystem property

Comment: @Sir Rufo Actually content of the label isn't just the selected item. It will be something else according to item.

Comment: Ok, then the answer to your question is: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can pass in any action you want to perform after the value you are setting. The sample below shows a case where you have a value that concatenates two strings for a FirstName and a LastName. This will only execute when the property is changed, so if the value is `Dan` and the new value is `Dan` it will not execute since it will not raise PropertyChanged in the first place.

```
public class ViewAViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get => _firstName;
        set => SetProperty(ref _firstName, value, () => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
    }
    private string _lastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get => _lastName;
        set => SetProperty(ref _lastName, value, () => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FullName));
    }

    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

Comment: what if one of the property is an observable collection of an object with value field and the second property is a sum of value of the collection? how to notify a change of an item inside a collection?

Comment: @AbdelkrimTabetAoul your question goes outside of the scope of this question and would best be asked as a new question.

Comment: i created a new topic as you suggested, here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64982977/notify-item-changes-in-observable-collection-in-wpf-c