# Notify item changes in observable collection in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, prism

In my WPF project, i have a `Service`
EF model defined as

```
public class Service
{
  public int ID
  public string Name
  public decimal Price
}
```

and in my viewmodel i have.

```
public class ReceiptViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Service> _services;
    public ObservableCollection<Service> Services
    {
        get { return _services; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _services, value, () => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Total))); }
    }

    public decimal Total => Services.Sum(s => s.Price);
}
```

Total is bound to a textblock in my view and and my observable collection is bound to an itemscontrol with textbox inside.

i want my Total textblock to change everytime the user change one of the price in my collection from the UI. how can i achieve that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 hope this can help :)

Comment: `I change one of the price` does this change come from the database or from the user? Can the database change at all on it's own (i.e. without the user doing anything)?

Comment: @Haukinger i edited my question, the price is supposed to be modified from the UI

Comment: Does BindableBase implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes it does. His question tags "Prism" and BindableBase in Prim implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Could you provide more info on what is currently happening? Also please change your getter & setter for Total as follows - public Decimal Total { { get { return _total; } set { SetProperty(ref _total, Services.Sum(s=>s.Price)); } }

Comment: @Bandook i've changed the code like this public decimal Total => Services.Sum(s => s.Price);

Comment: @Bandook i'll make Total as a read only property

Comment: @AbdelkrimTabetAoul I have posted an answer, let me know if any issues.

Comment: @Bandook i want to notify Total everytime there is changes on the collection or one item property inside the collection

Comment: @AbdelkrimTabetAoul yes, see my answer below. It'll change the total everytime the "Price" textbox value is changed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64982977/notify-item-changes-in-observable-collection-in-wpf-c/65001670#65001670

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225082/discussion-between-abdelkrim-tabet-aoul-and-bandook).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement it yourself, my example of observable collection (and also you need to subscribe and Raise OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Total))) when collection item was changed, or change my implementation of collectionEx to raising collection changed event.

```
    public class ObservableCollectionEx<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollectionEx(IEnumerable<T> initialData) : base(initialData)
  {
      Init();
  }

  public ObservableCollectionEx()
  {
      Init();
  }

  private void Init()
  {
      foreach (T item in Items)
         item.PropertyChanged += ItemOnPropertyChanged;

      CollectionChanged += FullObservableCollectionCollectionChanged;
  }

  private void FullObservableCollectionCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      if (e.NewItems != null)
      {
         foreach (T item in e.NewItems)
         {
            if (item != null)
               item.PropertyChanged += ItemOnPropertyChanged;
         }
      }

      if (e.OldItems != null)
      {
          foreach (T item in e.OldItems)
          {
              if (item != null)
                  item.PropertyChanged -= ItemOnPropertyChanged;
          }
      }
  }

    private void ItemOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        => ItemChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler ItemChanged;
}
```

Comment: OP is using Prism MVVM (see the inheritence BindableBase & the question tags). Though his question is not very clear, i don't the think the collection changes - only the selection from the collection changes.

Comment: @Lana i've changed the code from the topic to notify Total for the collection changes, i hope i dit it right

Comment: @AbdelkrimTabetAoul if my answer was useful you could mark it as right answer.

Comment: @Lana yes it helped me, i tweaked your code and use your advices, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow @Haukinger and @Bandook advices and i made this

The Model

```
public class Service
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

The View model that extends the model

```
public class ServiceViewModel : Service, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private decimal price;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PriceChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ServiceViewModel()
    {
    }

    public ServiceViewModel(decimal value)
    {
        this.price = value;
    }

    public new decimal Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set
        {
            price = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    // The calling member's name will be used as the parameter.
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string price = null)
    {
        PriceChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(price));
    }
}
```

The Main View Model

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _title = "Prism Application";
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }

    private string _firstName = "TABET AOUL";
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _firstName, value, ()=> RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FullName))); }
    }

    private string _lastName = "Abdelkrim";
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _lastName, value, () => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FullName))); }
    }

    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

    private ObservableCollection<ServiceViewModel> _services = new ObservableCollection<ServiceViewModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceViewModel> Services
    {
        get { return _services; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _services, value, () => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Total))); }
    }

    public decimal Total => Services.Sum(s => s.Price);

    public DelegateCommand AddServiceCommand { get; set; }

    public void AddService()
    {
        var item = new ServiceViewModel { Name = "Service", Price = 100 };
        item.PriceChanged += Item_PriceChanged;
        Services.Add(item);
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Total));
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        var item = new ServiceViewModel { Name = "Service", Price = 100 };
        item.PriceChanged += Item_PriceChanged;
        Services.Add(item);
        AddServiceCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action(AddService));
    }

    private void Item_PriceChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Total));
    }
}
```

The Code seems to work fine, when i change the price of one of the collection item, the Total change in my UI except when i add new item, so i called RaisePropertyChanged manually on clickcommand.

Anyone who have a more elegant solution is welcome

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward, but tedious:

1. Create a `ServiceViewModel` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`
2. Map the collection from the database to the observable collection of view models (`ReceiptViewModel.Services`)
3. Listen to all changes of the observable collection and attach to `PropertyChanged` of all added items (and detach from all removed items, also attach all items initially present)
4. Whenever one of the `ServiceViewModels` changes, set the new `ReceiptViewModel.Total` (or raise `ReceiptViewModel.PropertyChanged` if you make that a computed property)
5. Also update the database when a `ServiceViewModel` or the collection of view models change

Step 3 may or may not be easier/simpler/more obvious if you use the `EventAggregator` instead.

Comment: if i understand the second step, i must replace ObservableCollection<Service> by Observable Collection<ServiceViewModel>, but how to map to the DB?

Comment: @AbdelkrimTabetAoul this answer is not applicable to you as you are using Prism & your viewmodel is already using INotifyPropertyChanged since you are inheriting from BindableBase.

Comment: @Bandook please note that he has _no_ view model for `Service`, i.e. the class whose property (`Price`) is changed to trigger the change to `ReceiptViewModel.Total`

Comment: @AbdelkrimTabetAoul exactly this, for the initialization you could do something like `_services = new ObservableCollection<ServiceViewModel>( database.Services.Select( x => { var item = new ServiceViewModel( x ); item.PropertyChanged += PriceChanged; return item; } ) );` Note that this maps only _from_ the database _to_ the view, if you need two-way synchronization, things get complicated.

Comment: @Haukinger Sorry I should have been more elaborate, I meant he is already using Prism and can use out of the box implementations to notify changes either through Commanding or IEventAggregator. Which will simplify two-way synchronization as well. It'll also have an easier validation implementation (if needed)

Comment: @Bandook that's what the last paragraph of my answer is about. But he still needs a class to trigger the event/command. And unless he wants to put the code in xaml and code-behind of each and every control that might ever be used for changing the price (`DataGrid`, `TextBox`, `SpinEdit`, `Slider`...) which also will be near-untestable, he needs a view model for the item.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear - what happens with your current implementation? Any errors? Any breakpoint analysis we should be aware of? How are your bindings implemented in the Xaml

Until further info provided, here is a generic answer with what you have provided.

I would make the following changes to your ReceiptViewModel, taking full advantage of Prism MVVM.

```
public class ReceiptViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Service> _services;
    public ObservableCollection<Service> Services
    {
        get { return _services; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _services, value); }
    }

    private decimal _total;
    public decimal Total
    {
        get { return _total; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _total, Services.Sum(s => s.Price)); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand PriceChangedCommand {get; set;}
    
    public ReceiptViewModel()
    {
       PriceChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnPriceChanged);
    }

    private void OnPriceChanged()
    {
       Total = Services.Sum(s=>s.Price);
    }
}
```

Now in your XAML (not sure what it looks like currently) so this is an example

```
<!--Ensure your DataContext / ItemsSource is set correctly-->    
<TextBox Text={Binding Price}>
   <b:InteractionTriggers>
      <b:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
          <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command={Binding DataContext.PriceChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
          <!--Your AncestorType will be your root (top level) e.g. Window/UserControl etc-->
      </b:EventTrigger>
   </b:InteractionTriggers>
</TextBox>
```

You may not need the RelativeSource binding, as I said - I do not know your current implementation hence I have given a more complex answer that will work in a larger scenario. but you can try the simpler version -

```
<prism:InvokeCommandAction Command={Binding PriceChangedCommand} />
```

To add such **Behavior** to xaml, you might need to use "Blend for Visual Studio" (should be already installed with Visual Studio). Or try to do it without Blend by adding the following namespace in your Window/Usercontrol

```
xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

And installing the following Nuget Package - `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`